# Wordpress - How to schedule function to run every 48 hours

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, cron, schedule

I have a series of quotes saved in my database, and I want a singe, random quote to be pulled from the database and displayed on my site every 48 hours.

I've found code for scheduling this to happen using a custom cron scheduled event for every 48 hours. However, I'm assuming I'm implementing it incorrectly because although a single random quote is showing up on the site, it is switching to a new random quote every time the page is refreshed, as opposed to once every 48 hours.

```
function quote_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
$schedules['every_two_days'] = array(
    'interval' => 172800, // Every 48 hours
    'display'  => __( 'Every 48 hours' ),
);
return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'quote_custom_cron_schedule' );

//Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'quote_cron_hook' ) ) {
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_two_days', 'quotes_cron_hook' );
}

//Hook into that action that'll fire every 48 hours
 add_action( 'quotes_cron_hook', 'quotes_cron_function' );

//Function that executes via cron
function quotes_cron_function() {
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'quote',
'orderby' => 'rand',
'posts_per_page'=> 1,
);

  $quotes = new WP_Query( $args );
  $quotes_output = '';

  if( $quotes->have_posts() ):
    while ( $quotes->have_posts() ) : $quotes->the_post();
      $quotes_title = get_the_title();
      $quotes_content = get_the_content();
      $quotes_output .= '<div id="quote"><p>&quot;' . $quotes_content . '&quot;</p><p class="quote-name">' . $quotes_title . '</p></div>';
    endwhile;
  else:
      $quotes_output = '';
  endif;

  wp_reset_postdata();
  echo $quotes_output;
}
```

I then have the following in my header.php file:

```
<?php do_action( 'quotes_cron_hook' ); ?>
```

This is executing the function, but it executes every time the page is refreshed. I need the function to wait 48 hours before changing the quote again. I feel like I'm probably missing something simple here.

Comment: The wp scheduler can only run when an active request takes place, so the wp scheduler can only grantee that a job will not run before a given time.  There is no grantee that it will run at a specific time after that, it runs on the next request after the allotted time.

Comment: Just so you're aware, WordPress cron jobs aren't actually cron jobs. Whenever someone visits a page that triggers your script, WordPress will check to see if that cron job has run within the scheduled window yet. If not, then it will run, otherwise it will be ignored. It will _not_ be triggered automatically. The only way to have it run automatically is to either 1) set up an actual cron job on the server (probably not possible for you), or 2) create a separate service designed to visit that page periodically for you (your best bet) to force the WordPress cron job to run.

Comment: @B.Fleming - I forgot about doing a request to the site, this is actual something I should remember, I'm making a wordpress plugin that almost requires the use of CRON, but setting it up for plugin users is somewhat hard.  So that is a service I can add to my site. ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is likly this:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'quote_cron_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_two_days', 'quotes_cron_hook' );
}
```

Where you have `quote_cron_hook` insted of `quotes_cron_hook` one has a `s` one doesn't.  This mismatch will cause the condition to never fail, because the event is named wrong, it is never scheduled, and this condition passes on every single request.  Which in turns runs the `wp_schedule_event` function with a start time of `time` (see below).

If you look at the documentation for `wp_schedule_event` link below. The first argument where you have `time()` is this

> **$timestamp** (integer) (required) The first time that you want the event to occur. This must be in a UNIX timestamp format. WP cron uses UTC/GMT time, not local time. Use time(), which is always GMT in WordPress.

Note this **The first time that you want the event to occur**, with `time()` that is right now, and because it's named wrong it executes this every page load and then runs right now.

You can of course set `time()` to something else, but it will just mask the problem.

**Other stuff**

This may also be wrong.

```
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_two_days', 'quotes_cron_hook' );
```

more specifically, looking at the documentation

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

> **$recurrence** (string) (required) How often the event should reoccur. Valid values:
>
> - hourly
> - twicedaily
> - daily
>
> Default: None

I don't see `every_two_days` in there, unless it's undocumented.  To be honest I haven't used the WP scheduler much.  The `Default: None` is probably what you actual have here, as WP doesn't recognize that value so it falls back to none.  But what exactly that does I am not sure.

**Even more Other stuff**

As I said in the comments (and that may be ok for your use, but keep it in mind)

> The wp scheduler can only run when an active request takes place, so the wp scheduler can only grantee that a job will not run before a given time. There is no grantee that it will run at a specific time after that, it runs on the next request after the allotted time

Add this to wp-config.php

```
 define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

Disable the built in cron/scheduler.  Then go into C-Panel or edit crontab  (crontab -e) and add this cron job to run every minute (or some useful interval)

```
 php -q pathtowp/wp-cron.php
```

What this does, it take the control of the scheduar timing away from wordpress and give it to the "actual" CRON application (on linux).  That way it's not relying on page loads.

But, as I said and because this is a post someone should view, the normal WP behavior may be perfectly fine for you as it is.  Generally if I do anything with the scheduler I just rely on real CRON, which is why I mentioned it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking about this the wrong way. You have `do_action( 'quotes_cron_hook' )` in your header, which will fire the `quotes_cron_hook` action every time the page loads, which then allows `quotes_cron_function()` to hook into that action every time it fires. This seems consistent with the behavior you reported.

The thing is, setting a WP cron job doesn't force a a hook to **only** run at that particular interval. In your case, the `quotes_cron_hook` action fires every time the page loads, but it also fires once every 48 hours.

It seems to me like your desired functionality is to pull a "temporary" quote, but then change it every 48 hours. To do that, you would want something like:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'change_quote_hook' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_two_days', 'change_quote_hook' );
}

add_action( 'change_quote_hook', 'change_quote_function' );

function change_quote_function() {
      $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'quote',
          'orderby' => 'rand',
          'posts_per_page'=> 1,
      );

      $quotes = new WP_Query( $args );
      $quotes_output = '';

      if( $quotes->have_posts() ):
          while ( $quotes->have_posts() ) :
              $quotes->the_post();
              // Set the temporary post using a WordPress option
              update_option( 'quote_post', get_the_ID() );
          endwhile;
      endif;

      wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

The cron job will then fire this function once every 48 hours (more or less as people have pointed out) and set the quote where it can then be displayed. Then, your header can do the action to display the quote every time the page loads.

```
add_action( 'display_quote', 'display_quote_function' );
function display_quote_function() {
    // Get the quote post ID
    // The default, 1, will be returned if the option is not set
    $quote_id = get_option( 'quote_post', 1 );

    $quote = get_post( $quote_id ); 
    $quotes_title = quote->post_title;
    $quotes_content = quote->post_content;
    $quotes_output = '<div id="quote"><p>&quot;' . $quotes_content . '&quot;</p><p class="quote-name">' . $quotes_title . '</p></div>';
    echo $quotes_output;
}

do_action('display_quote');
```

Comment: Ok. I understand your logic here, and it does seem that it would work. However, I'm still not quite sure of the proper way to set the values in change_quote_function and then retrieve in display_quote_function. Would I just save them as normal variables the way I'm already doing it? Or is there some specific method I would use.

And I'm assuming I would still run the do_action('display_quote') in the header?

Comment: Would I use global variables? Also, what would set the quote for the first time (it's initial state)?

Comment: @jasonTakesManhattan One option would be to store the post ID in a WordPress option. I edited my answer to do it that way. You can also specify a default quote this way. If you're using the post ID like I do in the example, the default value should be the post ID of the default quote.